# String Time to actual Time

Tags: java, time, jgrapht

what I am trying to do is create an itinerary of flight paths using `JGraphT`. The problem I am facing is converting the string times I have set into actual times that I can then do calculations over multiple days i.e. if a flight leaves at 16.00 and arrives at 18.30 but then the connecting flight leaves at 14.00 and arrives at the final destination at 16.00 it will have been 24 hours (i.e. one day). I am lost in this as I have tried to parse the string to a date in the Flight class and also used The simple date format which is causing errors.

My code as follows;

**Flight3.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;   
import org.jgrapht.alg.DijkstraShortestPath;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph;

public class Flight3
{
private static ArrayList<String[]> myEdges;
private static ArrayList<Flight> flight;

public Flight3()
{
} 



public static void main(String [] args)
{
    myEdges = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    flight = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> Graph = createGraph();

    System.out.println("Airlines!");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the airport you wish to fly from");
    String startVertex = sc.nextLine();
    while(!Graph.containsVertex(startVertex))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that airport does not exist. Please select another;");
        startVertex = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter destination airport");
    String endVertex = sc.nextLine();
    while(!Graph.containsVertex(endVertex))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that airport does not exist. Please select another;");
        endVertex = sc.nextLine();
    }
    calculatePath(Graph, startVertex, endVertex);
 }

private static SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> createGraph()
{
    SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> g =
        (SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>) new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
    {
        g.addVertex("London");
        g.addVertex("France");
        g.addVertex("Spain");

        createTwoWayWeightedEdge(g, "London", "France", 80);
        generateFlight("1600", "1830", "EH445", "0000", 80);
        generateFlight("0400", "0600", "HE452", "0000", 80);
        createTwoWayWeightedEdge(g, "France", "Spain", 130);
        generateFlight("1400", "1600", "HD123", "0400", 130);
        generateFlight("0400", "0600", "DH712", "0000", 130);
    } 
    return g;
}

private static void createTwoWayWeightedEdge(SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> g, String vertex1, String vertex2, double weight)
{
    g.addEdge(vertex1, vertex2);
    g.addEdge(vertex2, vertex1);

    g.setEdgeWeight(g.getEdge(vertex1, vertex2), weight);
    g.setEdgeWeight(g.getEdge(vertex2, vertex1), weight);

    String[] tmp1 = {vertex1, vertex2};
    myEdges.add(tmp1);
    String[] tmp2 = {vertex2, vertex1};
    myEdges.add(tmp2);
}

private static void generateFlight(String depTime, String arrTime, String flightNo, String locTime, int duration)
{
    Flight f = new Flight(depTime, arrTime, flightNo, locTime, duration);
    flight.add(f);
}

private static String textToPrint(String[] format)
{
    String text = "    ";
    for(int i = 0; i < format.length; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 6 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;

            case 1:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 15 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;

            case 2:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 10 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;

            case 3:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 10 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;

            case 4:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 15 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;

            case 5:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 10 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;
            case 6:
                text = text + format[i];
                for(int j = format[i].length(); j < 10 ; j++)
                    text = text + " ";
                break;
        }
    }
    return text;
}

private static void calculatePath(SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> g, String startVertex, String endVertex)
{
    DijkstraShortestPath path = new DijkstraShortestPath(g, startVertex, endVertex);
    path.getPath();
    List<Object> edges = path.getPathEdgeList();

    String item;
    int count = 1;
    double totalDuration = 0;

    if(edges!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("\n The lowest cost route is:");
        String[] labels = {"Flight.", "Leave from", "At", "On", "Arrive", "At", "Local Time"};
        System.out.println(textToPrint(labels));

        for(Object edge : edges)
        {
                item = edge.toString();

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(item, ":");

                String firstAirport = st.nextToken().trim().substring(1);
                String secondAirport = st.nextToken().trim();
                secondAirport = secondAirport.substring(0, secondAirport.length()-1);

                String depTime = null;
                String arrTime = null;
                String flightNo = null, locTime = null;
                double price, flightDuration;

                for(int i=0;i<flight.size();i++)
                {
                    if(firstAirport.equals(myEdges.get(i)[0]) &&    secondAirport.equals(myEdges.get(i)[1]))
                    {
                        Flight details = flight.get(i);
                        flightNo = details.flightNo;
                        depTime = details.depTime;
                        arrTime = details.arrTime;
                        price = details.price;
                        flightDuration = details.duration;
                        totalDuration = totalDuration + details.getDuration();
                        locTime = details.getLocTime();

                        String[] flightInfo = {count+".", firstAirport, depTime, flightNo, secondAirport, arrTime, locTime};
                        System.out.println(textToPrint(flightInfo));
                    }
                }
                count++;

        }
        System.out.println("Cost of route = £"+path.getPathLength());
        System.out.println("Total time in the air = "+totalDuration       +"hrs");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Sorry you can't fly there from " + startVertex);
}
```

**Flight.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Flight {
String depTime;
String arrTime;
String flightNo;
String locTime;
double duration;
int price;

public Flight(String depTime, String arrTime, String flightNo, String locTime, int duration){
    this.depTime = depTime;
    this.arrTime = arrTime;
    this.flightNo = flightNo;
    this.locTime = locTime;
    this.duration = duration;
}

public double getDuration(){
    double duration = Integer.parseInt(arrTime) - Integer.parseInt(depTime);
    return duration / 100;
}

public String getLocTime(){
    int value = Integer.parseInt(locTime) + Integer.parseInt(arrTime);
    locTime = ""+value;     
    return locTime;
}

public String getFlightNo(){
    return flightNo;
}


public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
}
```

Comment: with such "short notation" for time, how do we plan to capture a flight that departs today but arrives tomorrow ? The representation of "0400" and "0600" will only work if it starts today and reaches today as well. What if flights are around midnight ?

Comment: What does "duration" mean to you? Given your example data, it is *not* the elapsed time between departure and arrival. 1600-1830 ≠ 80. 0400-0600 ≠ 130.

Comment: Are these flights on particular days? Or just in general, ignoring anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time?

Comment: They wern't meant for particular days i.e. 19/11/2016 19.00 etc but the more I think about it I will probably need to have a date associated with flight so that if it goes over the 24 hour mark it would be 1 day + however many hours etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not exactly clear. But here are some general tips.

## Departure + Duration = Arrival

Do not focus on arrival. The arrival time is a *result* of [arrival + duration]. In other words, output not input. This solves your problem with rotating around the clock crossing midnight.

## Use objects, not strings

Use objects, not strings. Java has an excellent industry-leading date-time framework in the java.time classes. Use them. But do *not* use the notoriously troublesome old legacy date-time classes, the ones outside the `java.time` package. Use strings only as needed in the user-interface and for serializing data.

In particular, you should be looking at the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) classes. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### ISO 8601

And for serializing, stick to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats such as HH:MM for a time-only value with the colon being optional for the “basic” version though I recommend keeping the colon for the “extended” version. The java.time classes use the extended version of ISO 8601 by default when parsing and generating strings that represent date-time values.

## Make `Flight` ignorant of charting, and vice-versa

Separate out your data model from the chart drawing. Define `Flight` as just the flight info and functions, without thinking about the charting.

```
class Flight {
    LocalTime departure;
    Duration duration;

    LocalTime getArrival() {
        LocalTime arrival = departure.plus( duration );
        // If called *many* times, and you account for changing-data and thread-safety, you could cache this result for performance. 
        return arrival;
    }

    Flight( LocalTime departureArg , Duration durationArg ) {
        this.departure = departureArg;
        this.duration = durationArg;
    }
}
```

To produce the exact data needed by chart, either use getter methods on Flight or a mediating class between Flight and chart. Keep the classes as cleanly separated as possible. Your car’s radio-stereo does not need to know anything about the air-conditioner which in turn does not need to know about the engine’s fuel-oxygen mixture ratio.

## Time Zone

The big elephant in the room is time zone. You have not made clear your intentions here.

Generally best to work in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Translate to a local time zone only as needed for presentation to the user.

Not much more to say on this until you clarify the intention of your business context.

Search Stack Overflow for the Java classes `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneOffset`, and `ZoneId` to learn much more.

Answer (score 0):

We might have to append/prefix some format of today's date (examples here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) before doing the duration computation.

so when we have the start time of "0430" we will prefix some format of today's date as well . For example:
`startDate = "0430"`

becomes

`startDateModified = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date()) + startDate;
startDateObject = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm").parse(statDateModified)`

similarly we do so for the end date (we might have to use some other value of new Date() because the arrival time be for the next day etc)

And then we do the computation.

Now regarding your question, we will have to some how figure out the connecting flight departure date value is not

`new Date(); //today`

but

`new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*3600); //tomorrow`

We might, in fact, have to have another shorthand notation to denote that the flight leaves today and reaches tomorrow  (like "+1 0430" to denote +1 day etc)